# How to expand BeautifulSoup HREF search from <a> to <td>

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, href

I'm trying to find certain hrefs within HTML and I had been using (which had been working):

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if a['href'].startswith('/game/'):
        chunk = str(a).split('''"''')
        game = chunk[3]
```

for the following HTML:

```
<td colspan="4">
    <a href="/game/index/4599712?org id=418" class="skipMask" target="TEAM_WIN">35-28 </a>
</td>
```

my code successfully gave me the /game/index/4599712?org id=418

However, there are other tags that have separate hrefs for the teams, and the record of the teams. Example:

```
<td nowrap bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <a href="/team/145/18741">Philadelphia</a> == $0
    " (3-1)                                     "
</td>
```

I would like some advice with this. I THINK I want to 1) if the href starts with "/game/" id like to have a better way of getting that href than splitting on quotation marks (probably regular expressions?). 2) If the href starts with "/team/" Id like to be able to create a dictionary to pair Philadelphia with (3-1). Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can get attribute values directly via the API, as you already did in `a['href']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab all `href` that start with `/game/` just append the found node `href` value to a list:

```
>>> result1 = []
>>> for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if a['href'].startswith('/game/'):
        result1.append(a['href'])

>>> print(result1)
['/game/index/4599712?org id=418']
```

As for the second one, you may use a regex, but on the plain text of the next sibling to `a`:

```
>>> import re
>>> result2 = {}
>>> for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if a['href'].startswith('/team/'):
        m = re.search(r"\((\d+-\d+)\)", a.next_sibling.string)
        if m:
            result2[a.string] = m.group(1)
        else:
            result2[a.string] = ""

>>> print(result2)
{'Philadelphia': '3-1'}
```

The `\((\d+-\d+)\)` will extract digits + `-` + digits that are inside parentheses. If this value is not present, a key-value will be added with the found key, but an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selectors for matching tag attributes that start with certain string: e.g. `soup.select('a[href^="/game/"]')` will match all `<a>` tags with attribute href starting with `/game/`.

For the second part, you can use `re` module:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = '''
<td colspan="4">
    <a href="/game/index/4599712?org id=418" class="skipMask" target="TEAM_WIN">35-28 </a>
</td>
<td nowrap bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <a href="/team/145/18741">Philadelphia</a> == $0
    " (3-1)                                     "
</td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('a[href^="/game/"]'):
  print(a['href'])

for a in soup.select('a[href^="/team/"]'):
    m = re.findall(r'\s*(.*?)(?=\s*==).*?(\(.*?\))', a.parent.text, flags=re.DOTALL)
    if m:
        print(dict(m))
```

Prints:

```
/game/index/4599712?org id=418
{'Philadelphia': '(3-1)'}
```